# Using Kafka with Micronaut

Tags: apache-kafka, micronaut

Are there any example projects showing how to use Kafka with Micronaut?  I am having problems with getting it to work.

I have the following producer:

```
@KafkaClient
interface AppClient {

@Topic("topic-name")
    void sendMessage(@KafkaKey String id, Event event)
}
```

and listener:

```
@KafkaListener(
    groupId="group-id",
    offsetReset = OffsetReset.EARLIEST
)
class AppListener {

@Topic("topic-name")
    void onMessage(Event event) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

My application.yml contains:

```
kafka:
  bootstrap:
    servers: localhost:2181
```

and application-test.yml (is this right and should it be in the same directory as application.yml?.  Also unsure how the embedded server should be used):

```
kafka:
  #  embedded:
  #    enabled: true
  #    topics: promo-api-promotions
  bootstrap:
    servers: localhost:9092
```

My test looks like:

```
@MicronautTest
class AppSpec extends Specification {

@Shared
@AutoCleanup
EmbeddedServer server = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer)

@Shared
private AppClient appClient =
        server.applicationContext.getBean(AppClient)

def 'The upload endpoint is called'() {
  // test here
  appClient.sendMessage(id, event)
  // other test stuff
}
```

The main problems I am having are:

1. My consumer is not consuming from my topic.  I can see the producer creates the topic in Kafka and the client group is created, but the offset stays at 0.
2. I am having problems when the test is started up where it looks as if two instances of the client are created and therefore the MBean registration fails (also, if I try to use the embedded Kafka, I get a different message about port 9092 already being in use because it tries to start the server up twice):

   javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: 
   kafka.consumer:type=app-info,id=app-kafka-client-app-listener
   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
   at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)

Comment: Have just discovered that the duplicate client problem was caused by having the @MicronautTest annotation on the test

Comment: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/

Answer (score 1):

You should add the embedded configuration `kafka.embedded.enabled` to a map with configuration and pass it to the ApplicationContext.run method.

```java
Map<String, Object> config = Collections.
    unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String, Object>() {
        {
            put(AbstractKafkaConfiguration.EMBEDDED, true);
            put(AbstractKafkaConfiguration.EMBEDDED_TOPICS, "test_topic");
    }
});

try (ApplicationContext ctx = ApplicationContext.run(config)) {
```

The consumer consumes from Kafka in another thread and you have to wait for a while until your AppListener catches up.
You can see a short example in [KafkaProducerListenerTest](https://github.com/lind/micronaut-kafka-test/blob/master/src/test/java/org/example/kafka/KafkaProducerListenerTest.java)

Remember the Kafka dependencies described in the Micronaut doc: [Embedding Kafka](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#kafkaEmbedded)

Comment: Thank you - very useful

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the second problem - the object passed into the listener did not have a @JsonCreator.  I found this out by trying to use the Jackson object mapper to construct the object from it's JSON while playing around.

If anyone else has the same problem - make sure that the object model works with Jackson before going any further!