# Micronaut 3+ and Kafka integration

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-kafka

I'm currently trying to get familiar with micronaut and Kafka. I've followed the documentation and created one KafkaClient in a microservice and one KafkaListener in a different microservice. The code looks like this:

Client. This is working as it's supposed to. I'm posting new messages in the vet-reviews topic:

```
@KafkaClient
public interface VetReviewClient {

    @Topic("vet-reviews")
    void send(VetReviewApi vetReviewApi);

}
```

Listener:

```
@KafkaListener(groupId = "pet-clinic", offsetReset = OffsetReset.EARLIEST)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class VetReviewListener {

    private VetService vetService;

    @Topic("vet-reviews")
    public void receive(@MessageBody VetReviewApi vetReviewApi) {
        log.info("Received vet review: {}", vetReviewApi);

        vetService.processVetReview(vetReviewApi);
    }

}
```

Although posting the message in the topic, the listener does not pull the new message. I've followed the official [micronaut-kafka integration documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/), but it does not work.

I know that this question was posted a while ago, but I don't see any answer and I'm unable to "revive" the problem by commenting because I don't have sufficient reputation.

[Link to old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117004/using-kafka-with-micronaut/53120501#53120501)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on the problem. I've changed the Kafka docker image and that was it.
Current working kafka-zookeper-kafdrop config:

```
 zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.1
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      # To learn about configuring Kafka for access across networks see
      # https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://kafka:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    ports:
      - 9100:9000
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT=kafka:29092
      - JVM_OPTS=-Xms32M -Xmx64M
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```